# Do SuperDrives work with IBM computers?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, optical-drive, pc

Do Apple USB SuperDrives work with IBM compatible computers?

If not, are there any advantages for buying a SuperDrive compared to a generic USB DVD drive?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the super drive is not different from any other optical drive.

I have removed the superdrive from my 2011 Macbook to make place for a second hard drive. I put the superdrive in a bay and can now use it as an external hard drive with my macbook or computer with another OS (such as Windows).

You could use any other external optical drive with your macbook. See for instance this post on macworld:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac/what-mac-compatible-dvd-r-drives-can-you-get-we-take-look-at-apple-superdrive-alternatives-3500390/